# TreeView template for a tree with circular type reference

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I need to display a tree bound to this kind of hierarchical objects:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name
    public List<Connector> Connector;
}

public class Connector
{
    public string Name
    public List<Node> TrueChildren;
}
```

so the actual children of a node are in the other object.

Cant make TreeView template to work with it. Seems like I need circular templates which is impossible in WPF. I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: How you gonna *present* on `TreeView` that circular relationship ?

Comment: the instances of Node all are different. n1.Connector(c1,c2,c3) where c1 = (n2,n3), c2 = (n3), c3 = (n4,n5,n6) where n2.Connector(c4,c5)... etc.. the values are not circular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily circular, it is only circular if the `Connector.Children` contain a reference to a node higher up on the current node path (and even that should be possible to handle somehow using virtualization).

Normally you just need to create two `HierarchicalDataTemplates` in the resources of the `TreeView` without any `x:Key` but the [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) set to the respective type.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Connector}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Connector}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding TrueChildren}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<TreeView.Resources>
```

(Using `x:Type` in the [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) is important, if you want to know why read the [property reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx))

Comment: you are right. my mistake was that I put those 2 templates into window.resource and tried to bind them by name.